# Cannot manage to pass a List to another method

Tags: c#, list

I am having a problem return a list so that i would be able to save it in a file and then load it so that the weights are saved and be retrieved another time. Sorry for the stupid question but how can i call and save the weights List from the SaveNetwork method , i cant grasp really what i can do to solve the problem. I know that i havent created a new instance of List weights however if i do that i will loose the current weights which are stored in this list.

```
public class Neuron
{
    private double bias;                       // Bias value.
    private double error;                      // Sum of error.
    private double input;                      // Sum of inputs.
    private double gradient = 5;               // Steepness of sigmoid curve.
    private double learnRate = 0.01;           // Learning rate.
    private double output = double.MinValue;   // Preset value of neuron.

    public List<Weight> weights;              // Collection of weights to inputs.      

    public Neuron() { }

    public Neuron(Layer inputs, Random rnd)
    {
       weights = new List<Weight>();

        foreach (Neuron input in inputs)
        {
            Weight w = new Weight();
            w.Input = input;
            w.Value = rnd.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            weights.Add(w);                    
        }          
    }

public static void SaveNetwork(string path)
    {

        FileStream FS = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter BF = new BinaryFormatter();

        BF.Serialize(FS,/* The List in this case is List weights ***/        );
        FS.Close();
    }

    public void LoadNetwork(string path)
    {
        FileStream FS = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter BF = new BinaryFormatter();
        weights = (List<Weight>)BF.Deserialize(FS);
        FS.Close();
    }
```

Update for this--I am using a similar hierarchical structure as the code below which was taken from Dynamic Notions blog which explains how to create a Neural Network. What i want to achieve is that after that the Neural Network has learnt i want to be able to save the List weights so that i would be able to load the weights if the program is stopped in order to skip the training of the network. So basically from the class network i want to access this list which is in Neural Class without creating a new instance in a new method else i will only get an empty List. Hope that its clearer coz i didnt know how to explain it better... Many thanks

```
public class Network{

//some variables.. 

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        new Network();
    } 
    public Network()
    {
        LoadPatterns();
        Initialise();
        Train();
        Test();
    } 

    private void Train()
    {
       double error;
       do
       {
       error = 0;
       foreach (Pattern pattern in _patterns)
        {
            double delta = pattern.Output - Activate(pattern);
            AdjustWeights(delta);
            error += Math.Pow(delta, 2);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0}\tError {1:0.000}", _iteration, error);
        _iteration++;
        if (_iteration > _restartAfter) Initialise();

    } while (error > 0.1);
} 

private void Test()
{
} 

 // Must be able to call and save the List<Weight> From here

private double Activate(Pattern pattern)
{
} 

 private void AdjustWeights(double delta)
 {
    _output.AdjustWeights(delta);

    foreach (Neuron neuron in _hidden)
    {
        neuron.AdjustWeights(_output.ErrorFeedback(neuron));
    }
 } 

 private void Initialise()
 {
    _inputs = new Layer(_inputDims);
    _hidden = new Layer(_hiddenDims, _inputs, _rnd);
    _output = new Neuron(_hidden, _rnd);
    _iteration = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Network Initialised");
} 

private void LoadPatterns()
{
}

} 

public class Layer : List<Neuron>
{

public Layer(int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        base.Add(new Neuron());
}

 public Layer(int size, Layer layer, Random rnd)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        base.Add(new Neuron(layer, rnd)); //this is where Neuron class is instantiated
   }

 }

public class Neuron
 {

    //some other vars 
    private List<Weight> _weights;              // This is the list in question. 

    public Neuron() { } 

    public Neuron(Layer inputs, Random rnd)
    {
      _weights = new List<Weight>();
      foreach (Neuron input in inputs)
        {
        Weight w = new Weight();
        w.Input = input;
        w.Value = rnd.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
        _weights.Add(w);
        }
    }


}
public class Weight
{
 public Neuron Input;
 public double Value;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried formatting your code when pasting it here? Also it would be nice to see small piece of your code, which you have problem with, not all sources of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` keyword from `SaveNetwork()` and use `weights` where you have your comment.

Comment: yes i know but what I didnt wrote my bad sorry for this , is that this method is being called from another class whereas i havent instantiated in the latter one. To explain better is that i have a class Form1 where i then call another class Network and from the Network class i called this neuron class ( where the list is located)  thats why i did the public static of this method. If i dont declare it as void then i cant call the SaveNetwork method directly from the Form1 class. If i instantiate Neuron class in the form1 class then i will loose the data in the weights list :/

Comment: @Etienne Do you understand what static keyword does? It declares that your method does not belong to or act on a particular instance of your Neuron class, but is instead a class method. You will not be able to access your weights property because it is an instance property. If you want to save the weights from the form, you need to do that via another method on your network class or resign such that form class has reference to Neuron class.

Comment: @raymond yep you have a point ... can you provide me with an example how to do it from the network class coz im literally without ideas on this..

Comment: @Etienne, I think you should change the design of your code. As I understand your last comment, `SaveNetwork()` and `LoadNetwork()` should be part of the `Network` class. (`LoadNetwork()` should maybe a static method that creates a `Network` to have kind of a _Factory_). Then I think the  `Weights` in `Neuron` should be a read-only property that is accessed in the `Network` class to do the saving. For loading you should add a constructor to `Neuron` that takes a `weights`-list to be initialized with.
I think this better separates the concerns and helps with your problems.

Comment: @cpt.jazz i've updated the code to show a smiliar structure to what i am using. Hope that it would make it clearer to what i want to achieve. Many Thanks

Comment: \@Etienne As cpt.jazz has said, you can pass in weights to a new Neuron constructor and leave saving and loading of weights to Network class. Therefore, during training, you save, you can skip and load otherwise.